Linear operator annihilates vector for every polynomial
I am working on this problem. I am studying for an exam.
Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$. Show that there is a non-zero vector $v \in V$ such that for all $f \in \mathbb{R}[x]$, $f(T)v = 0$ iff $f(T) \equiv 0$.
Now, the "if" direction seems trivial, if $f(T) \equiv 0$, then clearly $f(T)v=0$ for any $v \in V$. If I now assume that given a $v \in V$, we have that $f(T)v = 0$ for every polynomial $f$, wouldn't this tell me by Cayley-Hamilton that the minimal polynomial of $T$ divides any polynomial and thus I must have that $f(T) \equiv 1$? I don't know what else to do. Any help is appreciated.

Why does the action on a particular vector $v$ tell you anything about the minimal polynomial? Maybe the rational canonical form of $T$ will suggest a $v$.

From what I can remember, multiplying the rational canonical form of $T$ by a vector $v = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \ \vdots\  x_n \end{pmatrix}$ would give $\begin{pmatrix} -a_0 x_n \ -a_1 x_n + x_1\ -a_2 x_n + x_2\ \vdots\ -a_{n-1} x_n + x_{n-1} \end{pmatrix}$ where the $a_i$ are the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial, and since the vector $v$ cannot be zero, this would give $v = \begin{pmatrix} a_1\ a_2\ \vdots\ a_{n-1}\ 1\end{pmatrix}$. I am using that since $f(T)v = 0$ is true for all real polynomials, it is true in particular for $f(x) = x$. Is this correct?

Assuming a single block for the RCF, this looks about right. Maybe the term cyclic vector rings a bell.

I will have to review that. I will do that and then try again. Thank you.
